# PostgreSQL: Populate rows into a table only if the table is empty

Tags: postgresql

Writting a SQL script to create tables.
Among those tables are meta data tables.

I would like to insert these meta data, in SQL only if possible, only if :

```
1- The table is empty
   In this case all the values must be inserted

2- The table is not empty. In this case: 
   1. if the age_group key already exists, the table is updated with the new values 
   2. if the key doesn't exists, a new row is inserted
```

**Examples**

```sql
CREATE TABLE agegroup
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('agegroup_id_seq'),
    age_group text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    population integer
    CONSTRAINT pk_agegroup PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_age_group ON agegroup(age_group);

INSERT INTO agegroup(age_group,population)
VALUES ('0- 4',25435), ('5 - 9',25333)
```

| id | age_group | population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0-4 | 25435 |
| 2 | 5-9 | 25333 |

Then assuming the following INSERT (new age_group '10-14'):

```sql
INSERT INTO agegroup(age_group,population)
VALUES ('0-4',25435), ('5-9',25333), ('10-14',25311);
```

The table must look as follow:

| id | age_group | population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0-4 | 25435 |
| 2 | 5-9 | 25333 |
| 3 | 10-14 | 25311 |

While with the following INSERT (the age_group population changed from 25435 to 25335):

```sql
INSERT INTO agegroup(age_group,population)
VALUES ('0-4',25335), ('5-9',25333), ('10-14',25311);
```

The table must look as follow:

| id | age_group | population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0-4 | 25335 |
| 2 | 5-9 | 25333 |
| 3 | 10-14 | 25311 |

**Questions**

1. Saw a begining of solution around using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but seems it is only applicable for one value at time. Is there a simple way to achieve this with multiple values ?
2. In the case where the solution is too complicate, is there a way to INSERT into a table only if the table contains no data ?

So doing something like (dummy SQL):

```sql
INSERT IF TABLE EMPTY INTO agegroup(age_group,population)
VALUES ('0- 4',25435), ('5 - 9',25333)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, though in Postgres it's called [`ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT). And it *does* work on individual rows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS agegroup (
--           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
--     ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^ simple notation
    age_group text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    population integer
);

-- CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_age_group ON agegroup(age_group);
-- Don't create a second unique index, the `UNIQUE` keyword already does that

INSERT INTO agegroup(age_group,population)
VALUES ('0-4',25335), ('5-9',25333), ('10-14',25311)
ON CONFLICT (age_group) DO UPDATE
SET population = EXCLUDED.population;
```